# jQuery Remove Dynamic Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

I am adding information to a page by loading it when a table cell is clicked:

```
$('.bg_red').add('.bg_yellow').add('.bg_green').click(
  function() {
    var element_id = ($(this).attr("id"));
    $('#' + element_id).load('files/' + element_id + '.htm');
  }
)
```

The file loaded is a table with "Click to close" as the `<caption>`, which has the class "close_table" assigned to it.  As the loaded table has clickable links I cannot toggle the class (worked fine until I found out about the links within the loaded tables), so I need to make the `<caption>` element the item to click to remove the table from view.  The following is not working:

```
  $(document).on('click', '.close_table', function() {
    alert($(this).parent().html());
    $(this).parent().remove();
  })
```

The alert just confirms the code I want to remove, which properly shows the content within the table, but nothing happens following the removal of the alert.   I am now out of ideas as to why this is not working.  I am using jQuery v1.8.

---

The relevant HTML I must use (written by someone else):

```
<tr>
  <td style="border-left:0;border-top:0;border-bottom:0;text-align:right" class="observation">2744&nbsp;</td>
  <td>0.0%</td>
  <td style="border-left:1px dashed #606060  ;border-right:1px dashed#606060  " class="bg_yellow" id="2744_2013_10"></td>
```

---

The table that is loaded looks something like this:

```
<table class="display_this"><caption class="close_table">(click to close)</caption><tr><td></td><td style="border:0">01</td><td style="border:0">02</td>...
```

Comment: Can do you create a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Please include your relevant HTML structure.

Comment: The "relevant HTML" you posted contains no elements with the "close_table" class.

Comment: The close_table class is within the table that is loaded.

Comment: I do not know how to use JSFIDDLE but put reduced code at http://jsfiddle.net/CkAmh/2/

Comment: You are really shy on the provided code, based on your fiddle & html provided, you are trying to select elements with bg_red & bg_green classes and those do not exist, other than that provided info not enough.

Comment: also when does this code gets executed? onload, domready, something else??

Comment: There is an issue with .parent().remove(). Try to use .closest('form').remove() instead.

Comment: I've modified your fiddle (simulated the `ajax` job with `append`) and works clicking on the `remove` caption, [check this and find out the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/CkAmh/3/).

Comment: Also remember that, `ID` must be unique, it looks you have used same `id` for two elements.

Comment: I am shy with the code because I tried to pare everything down to the minimum so that it could be more understandable.  The HTML that was given to me as a starting point was 26 Meg in size (not a typo), so that had to be broken apart.  Even with the reduced HTML, there is plenty of cruft that would only complicate things.

Comment: Do you have two elements having same `id` ?

Comment: Are you inserting dynamic data to an element by clicking on the same element or have you different elements for clicking and inserting in another element using `id` ?

Comment: I am not seeing the same ID used for multiple elements - can you let me know where I am missing this?

Comment: Do you have something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/CkAmh/4/) ? If not update it's look and let me know.

Comment: When things were given to me I used the same element to load and remove.  After offering that code I was then told that the tables that were to be loaded would have clickable anchors, so using toggle() was no longer an option.

Comment: Thank you for the JSFiddle example.  I have very limited ability to change the HTML (I would not have done things this way) but will see if I can use the idea presented and apply it to what I have been given.

Comment: Just to close the loop on this, I was able to figure out what was going on, why my JSFIDDLE did not appear to work and why the example JSFIDDLE did work.  As it turns out, my code did indeed close the table.  What I did not realize was that the table was being reloaded, making it appear that it was not closing in the first place.  My task will now be to deal with this, which I should be able to do.  Thanks so much for the input, it was helpful in understanding this thing.